# Partial view in rails layput

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial-views

I want to render a partial in layout page i.e. application.html.erb and variable to it.
I created partial view in layouts folder "_fellowshi_sider.html.erb" and then added below code in application.html.erb

```
<%= render  "layouts/fellowship_sider", :entries => @entries  %>
```

I am not able to understand where do I set value for @entries variable. I wrote function in application_controller but it doesn't work.

Comment: Here you're passing local variable `entries` to partial, which is equal to `@entries`. So in your partial it should be without "@".

Comment: @entries is used inside the fellowship_sider? if yes then you need not pass it instance variables have scope entirely within the view. But if you still want to pass it, it should not be an instance variable and pass it using locales.

Comment: Or can you please provide more code, it's hard to tell with just one line of rendering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this partial is in your layout then you probably need the `@entries` object on every call so check that your method in application controller is actually being called, a before filter in the controller will do this for every action.

**Application Controller:**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :get_entries

  def get_entries
    @entries = Entry.all
  end
end
```

After doing this you don't need to pass the `@entries` variable to the partial, you can just access it directly in your partial view.

**Layout:**

```
<%= render "layouts/fellowship_sider" %>
```

**_fellowship_sider.html.erb:**

```
<% @entries.each do |entry| %>
  <%= entry.foo %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: need to pass entry variable <%= render  "layouts/fellowship_sider", :entries => @entries  %>

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<%= render :partial => "layouts/fellowship_sider", :locals => {:entries => @entries } %>
```

Thanks.